# How do I fix "borrowed value does not live long enough" from serde_json::from_slice without incurring a memory leak?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Consider the following piece of code:

```rust
pub async fn parse_bytes<'a, R: Deserialize<'a>>(_query: serde_json::Value) -> R {
    let result: Vec<u8> = vec![]; // fetch_result(&query).await

    serde_json::from_slice::<R>(result.as_slice())
        .expect("Can't parse bytes response")
}
```

#### Error

It doesn't compile:

```
`result` does not live long enough
borrowed value does not live long enough
```

#### Tentative solution

Providing `result.leak()` instead works, but I'm not sure it's the right solution: the method's documentation recites:

> This function is mainly useful for data that lives for the remainder of the program's life. Dropping the returned reference will cause a memory leak

And the returned reference is dropped as soon as the function ends.

#### Question

How do I fix the above without incurring a memory leak?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DeserializeOwned`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/trait.DeserializeOwned.html) instead.

```rust
use serde::de::DeserializeOwned;

pub async fn parse_bytes<R: DeserializeOwned>(_query: serde_json::Value) -> R {
    let result: Vec<u8> = vec![]; // fetch_result(&query).await

    serde_json::from_slice::<R>(result.as_slice())
        .expect("Can't parse bytes response")
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions before searching for duplicates.

Comment: I did look for a duplicate myself but missed it.

Comment: @doplumi not you, the answerer. They knew the magic keyword "`DeserializeOwned`" and could have searched. That's [what I did](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+rust+deserializeowned), for example.